# jenkins scripted Pipeline stage does not wait for its commands to finish executing

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have written a jenkins scripted pipeline which has 3 stages in it. And in each stage i am calling a curl command to start a jenkins job which is on my remote server. But, the problem is 2nd stage is getting executed before 1st stage completes its execution.
Please help me how to resolve this?

```
node{
   properties([
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
    ])
    stage('stage1'){
       sh 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{         "tagname": "$tagname" }" -vs http://pkg.rtbrick.com:8080/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=qwerty'
    }

    stage('stage2'){
        sh 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ "tagname": "$tagname" }" -vs http://image.rtbrick.com:8080/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=1234'
    }

     stage('stage3'){
       sh 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ "tagname": "$tagname" }" -vs http://image.rtbrick.com:8080/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=1804'}
    }
}
```

"Stage2" should start only if "stage1"  is completed.

Comment: Hi Jay, can you share the log from your job's execution please?

Comment: [Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] properties
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (build)
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -X POST -H Content-Type: application/json -d { tagname: ewetel-staging } -vs http://pkg.rtbrick.com:8080/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=qwerty
*   Trying 104.131.27.92...
* Connected to pkg.rtbrick.com  port 8080 (#0)
> POST /generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=qwerty HTTP/1.1
> Host: pkg.rtbrick.com:8080
> Content-Type: application/json
> Content-Length: 27
} [27 bytes data]
* upload completely sent off: 27 out of 27 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Comment: that's the complete log?

Comment: < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 220
< Server: Jetty(9.4.z-SNAPSHOT)
< 
{ [220 bytes data]
* Connection #0 to host pkg.rtbrick.com left intact
{"status":"ok","data":{"triggerResults":{"Refresh-Custom-Apt-Repo":{"id":702,"triggered":true,"url":"queue/item/702/"}}}}[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (trigger)
[Pipeline] sh
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Can you actually update your question with the complete log from your pipeline?

Comment: Jobs are working fine.. But the thing is it is not waiting for previous stage to complete

Answer (score 1):

It's doable using the Jenkins REST API and the `waitUntil` step in combination with `timeout` (without a timeout it could hang forever):

```
def response

timeout(30) {
    waitUntil {
        response = sh(
            script: 'curl http://pkg.rtbrick.com:8080/view/job/my-job/lastBuild/api/json | grep "\"result\":\"SUCCESS\""',
            returnStatus: true
        )

        return (response == 0)
    }
}

if (response != 0) {
    build.result = 'ERROR'
}
```

Comment: After which stage i need to place this?

Comment: @JayashreeRanganath after each stage where you need to wait for the job to be done. SO I'd said, inside each stage actually.

Comment: let me try and get back to you

Comment: I just added below lines to my pipeline. Triggered job is successful but still it is waiting and not coming out.

Comment: node{
stage('build'){
    sh 'curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ "tagname": "$tagname" }" -vs http://pkg.rtbrick.com:8080/generic-webhook-trigger/invoke?token=qwerty'


def response

timeout(30) {
    waitUntil {
        response = sh(
            script: 'curl http://pkg.rtbrick.com:8080/job/Refresh-Custom-Apt-Repo/lastBuild/api/json | grep "\"result\":\"SUCCESS\""',
            returnStatus: true
        )

        return (response == 0)
    }
}